# Cannot boot into recovery after changing file system of internal storage

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, odin

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 (GT-930F) and have been using it with an unofficial build of Lineage OS (which can be found [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/lineageos-19-0-android-12-signature-spoofing-for-s7-exynos.4368995)) for quite some time now.
But when I wanted to make a clean update to the latest build, I got the following error message in TWRP:

> Updater Process ended with ERROR: 1
> Error installing zip file /sdcard/lineage-19.0-20211220-UNOFFICIAL-herolte.zip

I thought reflashing TWRP with Odin might help but it didn't help with the error.

In trying to overcome this strange error, I (probably) totally bricked my phone. I thought the error might have something to do with the file system of the external sd card, so I changed it. That didn't eradicate the error so I had the (very stupid, as I now have come to realize) idea to change the file system of the internal storage to EXT4 (if I remember correctly).

As a result, TWRP is stuck in the loading screen and ODIN spits out a Write operation error if I want to reflash TWRP. I can still go into download mode, though.

Is this fixable or is my phone bricked?

Comment: check if adb shell works on TWRP splash screen, there you can repair file system with mke2fs or mkfs.f2fs otherwise flash stock ROM, unlock bootloader and start from scratch

Comment: Thanks a lot. Repairing the file system did not work for me but now I am back on flash stock ROM and can go on from there :)